# How to use Class<Interface> in method signature in Java

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to declare a method, which will take any class implementing an interface as its parameter. Example:

```
interface ICache {...}
class SimpleCache implements ICache {...}

void doSomething(Class<ICache> cls) { /* Do something with that class */ }
```

But when I try to call it with `SimpleCache.class`, it doesn't work. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about changing the method signature

```
void doSomething(Class<? extends ICache> cls) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce a type parameter:

```
<T extends ICache> void doSomething(Class<T> cls) { /* Do something with that class */ }
```

In Java, [a `Class<B>` is not a `Class<A>` even if `B` inherits from `A`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1743880). That's why it doesn't compile with `SimpleCache.class` in your case: `Class<SimpleCache>` is not a `Class<ICache>`.

Therefore, the solution is to introduce a type `T`: we're saying that this method can take any class `Class<T>` where `T extends ICache`. Since `SimpleCache` respects that bound, it compiles fine.